# Color only content of element

Tags: html, css

`background-color` colors the total size of the element, including padding and border. Is there a way to color only the content background without the padding and border?

Make only the 220px yellow.

```
div.ex {
    width: 220px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 5px solid;
    margin: 15px;
    background-color:yellow;
}
```

Comment: post some code please

Comment: Posted as per request.

Comment: you can do that by giving `display:inline` to `div`. Now the div will treated as inline element. check DEMO. http://jsbin.com/bocalulu/1/edit

Comment: We need to see the content of the div and some HTML

Comment: instead of padding, can you use margin and give separate color for border if required.

Comment: Add `display: inline-block` in your css. Check my answer...

Comment: @GeorgeIrimiciuc what about the posted DEMO, is that you are looking for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here we go for your div

```
<div>Some text or anything</div>
```

Set CSS like this:

```
div {
margin:0px auto;
width:100%;
height:50px;
background-color:white;
float:left;
padding:10px;
border:2px solid red;
position: relative;
z-index: 10;}

div:after {
background-color: grey;
content: '';
display: block;
position: absolute;
top: 10px;
left: 10px;
right: 10px;
bottom: 10px;
z-index: -1;
```

}

See [Demo](http://jsbin.com/epezip/968/edit)

Answer (score 0):

if I understood correctly, you could create an inner div with a 100% width, this will fill all the parent without the padding.

http://jsbin.com/bocalulu/5/edit?html,css,output

Answer (score 0):

```
div.ex {
width: 220px;
padding: 10px;
border: 5px solid yellow;
margin: 15px;
background-color:yellow;
display: inline-block;
}
```

**Example**

http://jsfiddle.net/2zDvK/

Answer (score 0):

you can do this trick

```
div.ex {
    width: 220px;
    border: 15px solid COLOR; /* COLOR - color of the background of the parent element */
    margin: 15px;
    padding: 0;
    background-color:yellow;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to color only the content background without the
>   padding and border?

Presumably the easiest way to simulate that would be to use an inset box-shadow of the same size as your padding.

***Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/z8q33/***

*Relevant CSS*:

```
div {
    width: 220px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 5px solid;
    margin: 15px;
    background-color: yellow;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 10px #ccc; /* same size as that of padding */
}
```